# Four different dice are rolled. How many outcomes of faces are possible where the sum is 14? Using non-negative solutions and inclusion and exclusion

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

$x_{i}$ =  the face of the i dice,  i=1,2,3,4

Determine the number of integer solutions of the equation

$x_{1}+x_{2}+x_{3}+x_{4}=14$

with the restriction

$1 \leq x_{i} \leq 6$

Converting the restriction, whe have:

$0 \leq x_{i}-1 \leq 5$

$x_{i}-1=y_{i}$

$x_{i}=y_{i}+1$

So, the new equation is

$y_{1}+y_{2}+y_{3}+y_{4}=10$

with the restriction

$y_{i} \leq 5$

But what do I do now? I know I have to use inclusion and exclusion, I was shown this formula below, but I don't understand what I have to do to find the values

$N=\left|S_1^c \cap S_2{ }^c \cap S_3^c \cap S_4^c\right|=|\Omega|-\left|S_1 \cup S_2 \cup S_3 \cup S_4\right|$

Comment: Fortunately in this case it's easy because it's impossible to violate $2$ of the constraints simultaneously.  So all you need to do is find out how many solutions there are with $y_1 \geq 6$ and then multiply by $4$ to get the number of "bad" solutions.

Comment: I would do in a different way : how many solutions for $y_1+y_2=k$, for each value $0\le k \le 10$, then how many solutions for $y_3+y_4=k$, for each value $0\le k \le 10$ (of course, it is same question), and finally, combine these 2 questions to solve your original question.